# How to add specific SQL result values to specific cells in a HTML table in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, datasource

I have a series of totals in a resultset see below:

[image: SQL Results]

What I would like to do is populate these results in a HTML table, but specific results need to go into specific cells ie split across different columns and different rows eg:

[image: Tables of Results]

Is there a Visual Studio control I can use for this or should I set up a html table with multiple data sources connecting to the database and then split up my query?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do.  Could you provide an example(s)? Also we cannot read your query in this image, you should post it as text/code instead.

Comment: Hi Barry. Thanks for your reply. No need to post the query as it works and I am happy with the output as above. Plus it's huge. Just to clarify I want to display this output in a HTML table, but a specific column from the results eg 4bC (10) to show in a specific cell in the table.

Comment: By cells are you meaning columns or is the result set needing to be split over multiple rows as well?

Comment: Thanks @James. Split over multiple rows.

Comment: Can you mock up a small example of the output? Is the required layout already decided by an external source or flexible?

Comment: Thanks @James just done that. Not sure what you mean about the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the mock, I was wondering how the cell is determined, I didnt explain that well at all! From what you have shown so far I can't think of a control other than a table that will hold that. If there is a set logic behind which cell is used for each value it may be worth doing a custom control.

Comment: Hi @James. That's the route I've gone down mate. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll mark it as the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks for the mock, I was wondering how the cell is determined, I
>   didnt explain that well at all! From what you have shown so far I
>   can't think of a control other than a table that will hold that. If
>   there is a set logic behind which cell is used for each value it may
>   be worth doing a custom control.

Good luck with it, Cheers